# What are these secrets in TBOI Afterbirth+

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac, the-binding-of-isaac-afterbirth+

I wonder what are the secrets 325, 339, 385. Couldn't find any info.

Answer (score 2):

The gamepedia wiki's [Achievements](https://bindingofisaacrebirth.gamepedia.com/Achievements) page includes the related secret numbers.

In particular, for the three in question:

- 325: "Participate in 31 daily challenges (they don't have to be consecutive; it will still count if you die in the first room)"
- 339: "Collect every item in the game, unlock all secrets and endings, and complete the bestiary"
- 385: "Sleep in 10 beds"